# MySQL to SQL Server SP or Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am having trouble converting this MySQL function into SQl Server or even to C# code for entity framework.

I will use this code with GEO Lite database so I can get the location information on an IP address.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE loc_id INT;

    SELECT geoname_id
    INTO loc_id
    FROM ip_blocks
    WHERE ip_to >= INET_ATON(TRIM(ip))
    ORDER BY ip_to LIMIT 1;

    RETURN IFNULL(loc_id, 0);
END
```

I tried creating this SQL Server function to replace the mysql function `INET_ATON`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ipStringToInt (@ip CHAR(15))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rv INT
        ,@o1 INT
        ,@o2 INT
        ,@o3 INT
        ,@o4 INT
        ,@base INT

    SELECT @o1 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 4))
        ,@o2 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 3))
        ,@o3 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 2))
        ,@o4 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 1))

    IF (
            @o1 BETWEEN 0
                AND 255
            )
        AND (
            @o2 BETWEEN 0
                AND 255
            )
        AND (
            @o3 BETWEEN 0
                AND 255
            )
        AND (
            @o4 BETWEEN 0
                AND 255
            )
    BEGIN
        SELECT @base = CASE 
                WHEN @o1 < 128
                    THEN (@o1 * 16777216)
                ELSE - (256 - @o1) * 16777216
                END

        SET @rv = @base + (@o2 * 65536) + (@o3 * 256) + (@o4)
    END
    ELSE
        SET @rv = - 1

    RETURN @rv
END
GO
```

And also convert the MySQL function to this version of SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IP2Location (@ip VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @loc_id INT

    SET @loc_id = (
            SELECT geoname_id
            FROM ip_blocks
            WHERE ip_to >= dbo.ipStringToInt(TRIM(@ip))
            ORDER BY ip_to LIMIT 1
            )

    RETURN IFNULL(@loc_id, 0);
END
GO
```

But I am getting errors like `Trim is not recognized built-in function name` which is strange because it is.

And getting an error on `@loc_id` which says it is expecting `(`

Would appreciate the help

Thank you

**EDIT #1:**
My function looks like this now:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IP2Location (@ip varchar(50)) RETURNS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @loc_id INTEGER 

SELECT top 1 geoname_id INTO @loc_id FROM ip_blocks WHERE ip_to >= dbo.ipStringToInt(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ip))) ORDER BY ip_to

RETURN isnull(@loc_id, 0);
END
go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For error:

> Trim is not recognized built-in function name

[`TRIM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) is only available starting in SQL Server 2017.

If you are not using that version, use `LTRIM(RTRIM(@ip))`.

---

For error:

> And getting an error on @loc_id which says it is expecting (

Instead of `IFNULL()`, I think what you are looking for is [`ISNULL()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)

---

For error:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator SELECT within a function

Instead of:

```
SET @loc_id = (
        SELECT geoname_id
        FROM ip_blocks
        WHERE ip_to >= dbo.ipStringToInt(TRIM(@ip))
        ORDER BY ip_to LIMIT 1
        )
```

Or:

```
SELECT TOP 1 geoname_id
INTO @loc_id
FROM ip_blocks
WHERE ip_to >= dbo.ipStringToInt(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ip)))
ORDER BY ip_to
```

Use instead:

```
SET @loc_id = (
        SELECT TOP 1 geoname_id
        FROM ip_blocks
        WHERE ip_to >= dbo.ipStringToInt(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ip)))
        ORDER BY ip_to
        )
```

Comment: Thanks man, I still get `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator SELECT within a function` but other erros are gone

Comment: Getting that error in this function: `IP2Location`?

Comment: I updated my question to show the latest version I have after your fixes, I get the error on the whole SELECT line

Comment: :) I was just about to recommend replacing the use of `LIMIT` with `TOP 1`, but you got that. Ok looking at your edit

Comment: It's your usage of the `SELECT INTO @loc_id`. You had it right the first time, just use `SELECT TOP 1 geoname_id FROM...`. Use `SET` like you did originally

Comment: hahaha its my first SQL question, so I dont know who is Gordon is, but you would have kicked his a** :)

Comment: Damn 650k, the dude is certainly active